# Bash - history search by ordered characters subset

Tags: linux, bash, search, command-history

I want to be able to write `dockercomex` and have, for example, a history match: `docker-compose exec (...)`. Searching like this works in PyCharm and it's fantastic for productivity. In Firefox it's similar, but with spaces between groups (`docker com ex` for that example).

Currently I use Ctrl-R in Bash, but it uses my whole phrase literally as one group (like `grep dockercomex $HISTFILE`). reverse-i-search doesn't seem to support any kind of regexps.

I could use: `history | egrep '(docker|com|ex)'`, but this isn't convenient for frequent use. If there's no better solution, I think I'll write a script that makes it a lot more convenient, something like: `recently dockercomex` - returning last n matches, asking if I want to execute any (default: the last one).

Comment: I find `search-history-*` much easier to use: my `.bashrc` includes `bind '"\e[A": history-search-backward'  ;# Up Arrow` and `bind '"\e[B": history-search-forward'   ;# Down Arrow`.

Comment: That's a fantastic tip, I use it a lot. But in this case I have a lot of commands in history with the same long prefix (like a lot of different commands executed in Docker). I know the distinct infix of what I want, but I have to wade through to get to the command: 
write some prefix → [Up] → go to start of wrong suffix → remove → write some more → [Up] → ... -- of course I use shortcuts (Vim mode even) to jump between words, but it's still wading like trying to fetch something of essence from Chrome's history via address bar. Well, not *that* bad, I always get there.